# Winter '16 breaks the Summer '15 Partner API with invalid soapType

Tags: soap-api, partner-wsdl, summer-15, winter16

With Winter '16 starting to appear on Sandboxes [I've started encountering problems with the Partner SOAP API](http://www.fishofprey.com/2015/09/salesforce-winter-16-breaking-soap.html).

The initial problem is around the new `soapType` enumeration values. In particular `<enumeration value="urn:SearchLayoutFieldsDisplayed" />`.

This `soapType` comes back from a call to `describeSObjects` with the sObjectType of "SearchLayout" for the "Fields Displayed" field.

Making the call against API v34.0 returns a field with this soapType. This in turn causes problems for the, in my case, .NET code that processes the SOAP XML response into strongly typed objects. This soapType isn't known or valid in v34.0 and results in an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (1, 2239646). --->
>    System.InvalidOperationException: Instance validation error: **'urn:SearchLayoutFieldsDisplayed' is not a valid value for soapType**.

Rolling forward to v35.0 of the Partner SOAP WSDL resolves the problem, but restricts the code to calling orgs that have been upgraded to Winter '16.

**Should using v34.0 of the Partner API only return results that can be handled by the corresponding WSDL?**

**Edit** - Raised as support case 12544039

Comment: I am using soap api 33.0, with winter 16 i am getting the following exception org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException: Unsupported type **urn:partner.soap.sforce.com VisualforcePage** does anybody have any idea on this ?

Comment: @KarunKumar I'd suggest asking a new question about your specific problem.   Include a SOAP call you are making if possible (which method are you calling).  Note that the complexType "VisualforcePage" was added in v35.0 of the Partner WSDL.

Comment: @KarunKumar Feel free to link to the new question from the comments here. If need be I can help with raising a support case.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Ballinger. I have posted a new question. below is the link
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/94205/winter-16-breaks-soap-api-33-0 how can i raise support case ?

Comment: I'll look into it. Please post this as a comment rather than an answer to the question above. You might need to earn a bit more reputation before this option becomes available to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a bug, you are correct that old API versions shouldn't start returning enumeration values added in later API versions.

---

Response from support for case #12544039

> R&D has set the bug corresponding to the issue - "New enumeration value of SearchLayoutFieldsDisplayed is returned in old api version, breaks old api clients" with the highest priority and the bug is scheduled for a fix on our next patch release ( 10/06[/15] ). After that patch fix, this issue shouldn't exist anymore.

Comment: Thanks. Will see what comes of my support case. Mostly published the question as a public service announcement in case others encounter it.

Comment: Sorry you're having trouble, i passed this on to the API team to look at.