# Winter '16 breaks soap API 33.0 DescribeLayout() with VisualforcePage

Tags: soap-api, partner-wsdl, winter16

We have an application that calls the DescribeLayout( ) API method using API version 33.0.  This method call began breaking in sandbox following the Winter '16 upgrade.
We are getting the following error
                **Unsupported type urn:partner.soap.sforce.com VisualforcePage**

Can you please suggest us on how to resolve the issue ? .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The complexType **VisualforcePage** was added to the Winter '16 Partner API in v35.0. In v34.0 and earlier it didn't exist.

```
<complexType name="VisualforcePage">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="tns:DescribeLayoutComponent">
            <sequence>
                
                    <element name="showLabel"              type="xsd:boolean"/>
                
                <element name="showScrollbars"              type="xsd:boolean"/>
                <element name="suggestedHeight"              type="xsd:string"/>
                <element name="suggestedWidth"              type="xsd:string"/>
                <element name="url"              type="xsd:string"/>
            </sequence>
        </extension>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

This element shouldn't be coming back with API calls using v34.0 or earlier. A support case should be raised so the API team can resolve it.

---

**Update from support for Case# 12570930**

> I have created this new case to address your query related to the version regression that we see in the Winter '16 Partner API call which is part of the describeLayout() call.
>
> The calls shouldn't show up in older API versions and the R&D has logged a bug to address this issue.

**Further update**

> R&D confirmed that this bug related to the new VF type for describeLayout() call in the v35 Partner API will also be addressed in the patch fix that we are going to have on 10/06[/15].

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Ballinger . How can we raise a support case with sales force ? I have tried to raise a ticket using the below link ( https://help.salesforce.com/HTUnauthContactSupport). But i am not able to raise .

Comment: You need Premier Support to raise a direct support case. I can raise one if you want, but I'll need to relay the details back to you. We could also try asking @superfell nicely

Comment: I already prodded some people on this, its been investigated.

Comment: @superfell, anyidea when this issue would be resolved ?

Comment: @KarunaKumarYatam See the Further update that I added to the answer with feedback from support. They are targeting a patch fix on the 6th.

Comment: @DanielBallinger,  I am still facing the same issue with Winter 16. Any idea whether the patch has been deployed or not ?